# diferencia entre objeto.propiedad vs objeto[propiedad]

Tags: javascript

```
    /*  property01.js
    define propiedades de un objeto
*/

var o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d: 4};

for (var i in o) {  
    console.log('o[' + i + ']: ' + o[i]);  
    console.log('o.' + i + ': ' + o.i);  
}  
/* salida  
o[a]: 1  
o.a: undefined  
o[b]: 2  
o.b: undefined  
o[c]: 3  
o.c: undefined  
o[d]: 4  
o.d: undefined  
*/
```

pregunta: porque o.a, o.b, o.c y o.d dan indefinido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te estás equivocando en tu planteamiento. No estás intentando

```
o.a
```

sino

```
o.i
```

En tu código

```
console.log('o.' + i + ': ' + o.i);
```

**esa** es la diferencia entre usar `[ ]` y no usarlo:

- `o[i]` -> **evalua** `i` y usa ese valor para buscar dentro de `o`.
- `o.i` -> **no evalua** `i`; se toma literalmente.

Se puede comprobar facilmente si haces

```
var o = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d: 4, i: '¡ Es verdad' };
```